# Displaying output with return parameter

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, function

Below is the simple code written by me

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.16 ;
contract blue
{
   string first ;
uint age ;
 

 function sett ( string memory fn , uint um)  public  returns (string  memory, uint )
 {
     first =  fn ;
     age = um ;
 }
```

I want that the value passed by me should be showed in remix console. However , when I enter values , txn is successful but values are not shown even though I am returning the values in function using `returns`. Can anyone please tell me what am I missing. I want that after I enter values and upon pressing Transact button , the values shall display .

[image]

Even in the decoded output my inputs are not being shown . What is the mistake being made by me

[image]

Answer (score 0):

actually it is not a `view` function and since you are changing the state of the block chain in your `gett` function it cannot be `view` at all, and if it is not a `view` function then `remix` does not prints the values.
So just create a `get()` function aside to get `string` and `uint` like this -

```
    function get () public view returns (string memory, uint) {
        return (first, age);
    }
```

That is how much I understand `remix`, I hope this will solve your problem. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any way to input and display through same function ?

Comment: Please refer to `solidity` official docs for more info, and I don't think so it is possible in `remix`. Thanks